# Rails asset query string changes randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is more easily explained by example:

When I go to http://www.learnmoreaboutthis.org/.

I get different URLS for logo:

```
http://www.learnmoreaboutthis.org/images/maximum_logo_height_500.jpeg?1380996549
```

That number in the last part changes.

How could I debug this? Any starting point is greatly appreaciated.

I am using Rails 3.0.9. My application has not asset pipeline.

## Update

Try reloading www.learnmoreaboutthis.org several times to see what I mean.

Comment: I don't see the number changing. I always get the same one you did.

Comment: "Debug" this? What makes you think it needs debugging? The page is essentially unusable anyway, and rendering incorrectly (I hope) on Chrome/OS X.

Comment: hmmm, number is changing for several machines. With debug I mean, how to know why that number changes... but if it's not changing for you ...

Comment: Why? It's a cache-buster.

Comment: I know that's a cache buster, but I don't know why it changes in several machines.

Comment: It changes on different *clients* or on different *servers*? And does it really matter?

Comment: well, when I reload it several times in my browser I get different images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but anyway it should work.

I'm assuming you are using `image_tag` helper, instead of that:

```
<img src="/images/maximum_logo_height_500.jpeg" alt="maximum logo" />
```

Hope this helps!